# GMAP.net slows down after using large number of markers

Tags: c#, memory, gmap.net

I am using GMAP.NET to mark fences. The problem I am facing is that my app slows down as I keep adding more markers, and in my particular case, becomes un-usable after marking ~(5k) points.
Secondly, when I monitor the ram consumption, I notice that the RAM usage increases proportionally with the addition of points up until it reaches ~40mb of usage, after which it increases very slowly. The memory doesn't free up even when I clear all the markers and fences..
What could be the issue here?